# how to change the test file run order in cypress in run time

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I have 3 different test files

1- testfile-1.js
2- testfile-2.js
3- testfiles-3.js

i can change the test file running order using testfiles feature in cypress.config file but i want to change the order runtime not hard coded.

looking for the solution

Regards

Comment: Tests should be independent of each other. What is your goal with having a test files executed in a specific order each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way

```
{
"chromeWebSecurity": false,
```

}

paste this in cypress.json and it will allow the external iframes to work in cypress

Comment: for people using chrome in cypress

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name to something like this in case you don't want to use `testFiles: []` in your `cypress.config`.

```js
01-testfile.spec.js
02-testfile.spec.js
03-testfile.spec.js
```

Comment: itll be still manually , i want to change the order in run time

Comment: How are you trying to change it with runtime using CLI or something else? What have you tried?

Comment: i have these 3 tests files , i am looking for something that ask me the order before I run the test. currently i am using testfiles [] array in config file to set the order

Answer (score 0):

You can comma-separate the file names on the command line,

```js
yarn cypress run --spec "testfile-1.js,testfile-2.js,testfiles-3.js"
```

Not sure if that guarantees the order though.

If no luck with that, it would be possible to guarantee the order by running with a special script (but it's more work).